# Unexpected Output From Rolodex Program, Unable to Troubleshoot

Tags: c++

Ive been working with the following rolodex program and header class file for a project and am trying to modify the program such that an input string that begins with a - causes that word (without the -) to be deleted from the Rolodex instead of inserted. For example, if the input is "the quick black fox jumps -black brown over the lazy dog" then the output would contain the word brown but not black. Its working for most scenarios however when i try the following test i get no output for some reason.

[image: Output Error]

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "Rolodex.h"

using namespace std;

struct RolodexStats
{
    int insertions;
    int deletions;
    int forward_rotations;
    int backward_rotations;
};

auto verbose      = false; // Log Rolodex actions
auto printCurrent = false; // Output only the current Rolodex card
auto duplicates = true; //allow duplicates
auto report = false; //report mode



void rolodex()
{
    string word;
    Rolodex<string> rolodex;
    RolodexStats statistics = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    while (cin >> word) {

        auto delete_check = false; //delete words

        switch (word.at(0)) {
            case '-':
                delete_check = true;
                word.erase(0, 1);
                break;
        }

        if (word.length() == 0)
            continue; // ignore empty words

        if (rolodex.isBeforeFirst() || rolodex.currentValue() <= word) {
            while (!rolodex.isAfterLast() && rolodex.currentValue() < word) {
                rolodex.rotateForward();
                statistics.forward_rotations++;
                if (verbose)
                    cerr << "rotateForward\n";
            }

            if (delete_check) {
                if (!rolodex.isAfterLast() && rolodex.currentValue() == word) {
                    rolodex.delete_current();
                    statistics.deletions++;
                    if (verbose)
                        cerr << "delete (forward)\n";
                }
            } else if (duplicates || rolodex.isAfterLast() || rolodex.currentValue() != word) {
                rolodex.insertBeforeCurrent(word);
                statistics.insertions++;
                if (verbose)
                    cerr << "insertBeforeCurrent\n";
            }
        } else if (rolodex.isAfterLast() || rolodex.currentValue() >= word) {
            while (!rolodex.isBeforeFirst() && rolodex.currentValue() > word) {
                rolodex.rotateBackward();
                statistics.backward_rotations++;
                if (verbose)
                    cerr << "rotateBackward\n";
            }

            if (delete_check) {
                if (!rolodex.isBeforeFirst() && rolodex.currentValue() == word) {
                    rolodex.delete_current();
                    statistics.deletions++;
                    if (verbose)
                        cerr << "delete (backward)\n";
                }
            } else if (duplicates || rolodex.isBeforeFirst() || rolodex.currentValue() != word) {
                rolodex.insertAfterCurrent(word);
                statistics.insertions++;
                if (verbose)
                    cerr << "insertAfterCurrent\n";
            }
        }
    }

    if (printCurrent) {
        cout << rolodex.currentValue() << '\n';
    }

    else if (report)
    {
        cout << statistics.insertions << " "
             << statistics.deletions << " "
             << statistics.forward_rotations << " "
             << statistics.backward_rotations << endl;
    }

    else { // Output all Rolodex card values (default)
        while (!rolodex.isBeforeFirst())
        {
            rolodex.rotateBackward();
        }
        rolodex.rotateForward(); // Go to the first card
        while (!rolodex.isAfterLast())
        {
            cout << rolodex.currentValue() << '\n';
            rolodex.rotateForward();
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "dvc")) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'd':
                duplicates=false;
                break;
            case 'v':
                verbose = true;
                break;
            case 'c':
                printCurrent = true;
                break;
            case 'r':
                report = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;
    rolodex();
}
```

```cpp
#ifndef ROLODEX_H_
#define ROLODEX_H_

template <class T>
class Rolodex {

public:
    //Creates a new empty Rolodex
    Rolodex() {
        sentinel_ = new Item;
        sentinel_ -> next = sentinel_;
        sentinel_ -> prev = sentinel_;
        current_ = sentinel_;
    }

    //Returns true if the Rolodex is positioned before the first card.
    bool isBeforeFirst() {
        return (sentinel_ == current_ );
    }

    //Returns true if the Rolodex is positioned after the last card.
    bool isAfterLast() {
        return (sentinel_ == current_ ); // change as needed
    }

    //Rotates the Rolodex one step forwards.
    void rotateForward() {
        current_ = current_ -> next;
    }

    //Rotates the Rolodex one step backwards.
    void rotateBackward() {
        current_ = current_ -> prev;
    }

    //Returns the value of the current card.
    const T &currentValue() {
        return current_ -> value;
    }

    //Inserts a new card after the current position and positions the Rolodex at the newly inserted card.
    void insertAfterCurrent(const T &value) {
        Item* coming = new Item;

        coming -> value = value;
        coming -> next = current_ -> next;
        coming -> prev = current_;
        current_ -> next -> prev = coming;
        current_ -> next = coming;

        current_ = coming;
    }

    //Inserts a new card before the current position and positions the Rolodex at the newly inserted card.
    void insertBeforeCurrent(const T &value) {
        Item* going = new Item;

        going -> value = value;
        going -> next = current_;
        going -> prev = current_ -> prev;
        current_ -> prev -> next = going;
        current_ -> prev = going;

        current_ = going;
    }

    void delete_current() {
        current_ -> prev -> next = current_ -> next;
        current_ -> next -> prev = current_ -> prev;
        Item* deleter = current_;
        current_ = current_ -> next;
        delete deleter;
    }

private:
    struct Item {
        T value;
        Item* next;
        Item* prev;
    };

    Item* sentinel_;
    Item* current_;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Why do you expect that `a b c -c` will remove `c` but _also_ `a`?

Comment: When you run this with a debugger, what is the *first* thing the program does incorrectly?

Comment: @ScottHunter apologies if this is a really stupid question. Im attempting to parse a text file to the program in clion through the command line by running rolodex.exe <txt -c but it keeps returning rolodex is not a recognised command or executable. The failed test result was from my universitys online checking system.

Comment: Im struggling to even open the debugger while passing the appropriate text file to it

Comment: So don't use a text file; just enter the input from the console.